# 1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: phpmyadmin

Hoje fiz um upload de uma DB no Phpmyadmin mas deu um erro

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Fui ver na table que deu erro, estava tudo normal, será que tem algum problema? ou tenho que tentar resolver o erro e faz novamente o upload?

Answer (score 0):

esse erro provavelmente aconteceu porque algum registro da sua tabela está com um valor da chave primária que já pertence a outro registro... cada valor de Primary key deve ser único em uma tabela.